# Using regex to find portions of a path where first portion is n digits only

Tags: regex

I would like a regex expression that will match the first 4 digit part of a path and then the next two parts. So it would find:

```
/58A2/D456-509F-4905-A473/FCAD1612CEDB/
```

in both of these lines

```
pyramid:/58A2/D456-509F-4905-A473/FCAD1612CEDB/filename1.tif
cache:/ThumbCache/58A2/D456-509F-4905-A473/FCAD1612CEDB/filename2.jpg
```

I tried

```
/.{4}/.*?/.*?/
```

and this works for the first one... but not the second one. Apparently the /ThumbCache/ is simply not matching because it's not 4 digits.

*** UPDATE ***

Ok... so this actually works, in this simplified example... in my actual code I had an extra /.*?/

It won't let me delete this post, because people posted answers. Not sure what to do.
shareeditdeleteflag

Comment: What regex engine/language are you using?

Comment: This might get you on the right track if you're comfortable working with capture groups: https://regex101.com/r/lG3sM5/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... so this actually works, in this simplified example... in my actual code I had an extra /.*?/

It won't let me delete this post, because people posted answers. Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this regex](http://regexr.com/3dt9h):

```
\/[0-9A-Z]{4}\/(?:[0-9A-Z]{4}-?){4}\/[0-9A-Z]{12}\/
```

Regex explanation:

```
\/           # Slash literal
[0-9A-Z]     # Match digit or uppercase letter
{4}          # Match previous exactly 4 times (So 4 digits/uppercase letters)
\/
(?:          # Start non-capturing group (Don't store the result of group)
    [0-9A-Z]
    {4}
    -?       # Optionally a hyphen (Last sequence doesn't have one)
)            # End non-capturing group
{4}
\/
[0-9A-Z]
{12}
\/
```

You will also need global or `g` flag to capture globally if you have multi-line input.

For input

```
pyramid:/58A2/D456-509F-4905-A473/FCAD1612CEDB/filename1.tif
cache:/ThumbCache/58A2/D456-509F-4905-A473/FCAD1612CEDB/filename2.jpg
```

this will match

```
/58A2/D456-509F-4905-A473/FCAD1612CEDB/
/58A2/D456-509F-4905-A473/FCAD1612CEDB/
```

I didn't add any capturing groups as you haven't specified anything that needs to be captured separately. You get the full match output.